# Set up path on prompt on pycharm terminal windon

Tags: macos, terminal, pycharm, prompt

I just upgrade pycharm into 2016.3.1. Before upgrade, I do not have problem to see the current directory path under the prompt on terminal window. After upgrade into pycharm 2016
3.1. All directory path on prompt on terminal window seems like messed up with `133;C;133;D;01337;RemoteHost=hawkins@pc_name.home1337;CurrentDir=/Users/hawkins/path133;MAC:path hawkins$ 133;B` for some reason. Anyone have expereience on how to resolve this?

```
MAC:path$
133;C;133;D;01337;RemoteHost=hawkins@pc_name.home1337;CurrentDir=/Users/hawkins/path133;MAC:path hawkins$ 133;B
133;C;133;D;01337;RemoteHost=hawkins@pc_name.home1337;CurrentDir=/Users/hawkins/path133;MAC:path hawkins$ 133;B
133;C;133;D;01337;RemoteHost=hawkins@pc_name.home1337;CurrentDir=/Users/hawkins/path133;MAC:path hawkins$ 133;B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for some reason, I figure it out by create a .pycharmrc under by user directories
and setting up `/usr/local/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.pycharmrc` under Tool->Terminal on shell path. It seems like it fixed but i have no idea why

```
MAC: path$ cat ~/.pycharmrc
exec bash
```

Comment: If you add this to `Preferences` > `Tools` > `Terminal` > `Shell path` there is a good chance it will break your terminal inside PyCharm. Record the value before you change it. Mine was `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. It turned out my problem was due to have iTerm shell integration installed. 
As you have tagged the question [osx], I assume that you might also have done this.

There is a nice explanation to what these strange symbols mean in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294886/47407

I figured I could avoid having to uninstall Shell Integration by clearing my `PROMT_COMMAND`, and setting `PS1` again. I made a shell script called `pycharm_terminal.sh` with the following

```
export PROMT_COMMAND=
export PS1="\[\e[31m\]\u\[\e[0m\] at \[\e[33m\]\h\[\e[0m\] in \[\e[32m\]\w\[\e[0m\] at [\A] \[\033[31m\]`git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -e ^* | sed -E  s/^\\\\\*\ \(.+\)$/\(\\\\\1\)\ /`\[\033[35m\]\n$ \[\033[00m\]"
bash -i
```

The `PS1` variable can be set to whatever you had before. This is just how I like mine.

Now, in PyCharm Settings: Go to Tools > Terminal and in "Shell path" set it to `/bin/bash <path_to_pycharm_terminal.sh>`.

Now try opening a new terminal in PyCharm. It shouldn't have those control character errors.

Comment: It can be remedied by following the instructions at this link: https://www.alexkras.com/remove-shell-integration-from-iterm2/ simply remove the file it places in `~/` and remove the entries added to `~/.bash_profile` (on OSX anyway)

Comment: Yes, but if you want to have iTerm Shell Integration on your usual terminal, but not in the PyCharm terminal you have to do some workaround instead of removing it outright.

Comment: Oh yeah for sure, just if people wanted to get rid within pycharm this is an easy way to do it

Answer (score 6):

Solution that worked for me:

1. Go to Settings > Plugins
2. Find plugin "Python Terminal" and disable it
3. Restart PyCharm

The only negative effect I've noticed - auto activation of virtualenv on terminal start doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

- Created new file pycharm_terminal.sh with one command `bash -l`
- Then I set PyCharm Settings: to Tools > Terminal and in "Shell path" set it to /bin/bash/path_to_pycharm_terminal.sh.
- Restart PyCharm and all work as expected

`bash -l`, by man, is a:  `-l        Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell (see INVOCATION below).`

which is probably mean, that when PyCharm starts the Terminal and executing the pycharm_terminal.sh with bash -l, everything in .bash_profile is include by default

Answer (score 1):

Found this question while trying to resolve similar issue for 'Geany' on mac osx. I had an install of iterm2 on my machine and was getting garbage in front of the terminal prompt.

similar solution as KPLauritzen offered also works for 'Geany' terminal as such.

Hope this helps someone:

1. Create shell script in home directory using desired PS1 & CLICOLOR settings:

   ## ~/geany_terminal.sh

   export PROMT_COMMAND=
   export PS1='[\e[1;32m][\u@\h \W] \D{%F %T}\n\$[\e[0m]'
   export CLICOLOR=1
   export LSCOLORS=gxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx
   bash -i
2. Then I went to 'Edit -> Preferences --> Terminal' and set my 'Shell' to:
   /bin/bash /Users/myusername/geany_terminal.sh

Upon reloading Geany, the Terminal now displays with PS1 and CLICOLOR settings exactly as I have set in my .bash_profile without garbage in front.

Answer (score 1):

You can just activate your `.bash_profile`

```
/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.bash_profile
```